# How to view document preview directly in the document libraries view (column)?

Tags: 2013, document-library

It is possible in SharePoint to get a preview of the selected document in the preview pane.

How can I implement the preview of the document itself, in a document libraries view directly (in a column)?

Is that possible?

Comment: Clicking the ... elipsis menu will bring up the document preview, is that sufficient?

Comment: No, i want to add the document "frame" directly to a view.

Answer (score -2):

Here you can find how to implement a "preview pane" 
i guess this article explain it better than me.

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2009/04/23/a-hidden-gem-the-preview-pane-view-in-sharepoint-aspx/

( btw this is my first answer dunno if i am supposed to link external web site )

Comment: This does not say anything about document preview, just list preview.